# Martin Luther Commentary on Galatians

Tags: martin-luther, galatians

Is there such a volume on Luther's commentary on Galatians that is in the original Latin with an English translation: an interlinear of sorts?

Comment: I can find many translations online but have yet to locate the original Latin, let alone an interlinear. Interlinear texts are very unusual for works of this kind. They are common for the scripture, but not for commentaries. Upvoted +1.

Comment: Thank you Nigel for your response though not very encouraging! :-)

Comment: I wouldn't give up. It may well be available, possibly from the USA, and possibly expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement to not "throw in the towel!" I'll continue my search!

Comment: According to Zondervan, the length of the original Latin is the issue. If published, it would be more than 1500 pages in length. I wouldn't be too hopeful to find a Latin version.